# Why USB hardwares are shown wrong in windows 7 32bit installed in virtualbox in the UBUNTU 1110 64bit

Tags: usb

I install windows 7 32bit in the virtual box on my 64 bit Ubuntu. windows 7 can see my usb devices but it always show usb hardware wrong.

I plug my usb disk in, can not work.

I plug my usb printer in, can not work.

How to overcome it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are permissions that need to be put in place for passing USB through VB in Ubuntu 11.10

"Add yourself to the user group vboxusers, then log out and back in, to make use of available USB devices. To do this via the graphical interface, click System Settings/Users and Groups/Manage Groups."

See :https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/USB for more information.